# How can I use pyqgis to only show point that do not share a common value?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have two layers of point data containing the coordinates of addresses from two different years. I want to display only the new addresses on the most recent dataset that do not exist in the database from the earlier year. To do this I am trying to use a feature which both layers contain, the value of which is a unique identifier for each address which is the same across years. I want to know how I can use pyqgis to display only these new addresses by making a script which will look through the feature in question on both datasets, and if the value of said feature on one dataset is the same as the other dataset, neither point the will be displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anything you tried yet? The direction to look at, if you want to go with python, would be list comparison. A simple unique = list(list1.intersection(list2)) should do it. But as you say database it might be much faster to use the abilities there and just open the connection to the database with python.

Comment: this is a  common advanced process in most all gis software. If you knew how to use the software first then the programming may come easier.